# MySQL aggregated records

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

table `father`:

```
ID  NAME
1   John
2   Paul
3   Mike
```

and table `child`

```
ID  FATHER  CHILD
1   1       Mary
2   2       Liz
3   2       Lucy
```

now I need a view `family` like:

```
FATHER_ID FATHER_NAME  CHILDREN
1         John         'Mary'
2         Paul         'Liz, Lucy'
3         Mike         NULL
```

What's the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a better

```
CREATE VIEW family AS
SELECT 
    f.ID AS FATHER_ID,
    f.NAME AS FATHER_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.CHILD) AS CHILDREN
FROM
    father f
LEFT JOIN
    child c ON f.ID = c.FATHER
GROUP BY
    f.ID, f.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

An option here:

```
SELECT f.id AS FATHER_ID, 
f.name AS FATHER_NAME,
GROUP_CONCAT(c.CHILD SEPARATOR ', ') AS CHILDREN
FROM father as f
LEFT JOIN child c ON c.FATHER = f.id
GROUP BY (f.id)
```